# How to use stored procedure or function in iBatis 3 (with annotation)

Tags: java, ibatis

I want to use Oracle stored procedure or function via 'iBATIS 3 for Java' with annotation.
But I can't find any sample codes.
Can anyone help me? I need a simple sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [discussion](http://www.mail-archive.com/user-java@ibatis.apache.org/msg15948.html) on [user-java](http://www.mail-archive.com/user-java@ibatis.apache.org/info.html) mail list on that.

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful.
Do you have any ideas about my another question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683289/how-to-get-a-result-from-output-parametersys-refcursor-of-oracle-stored-procedu